# Can't access user_id through params, between controllers/models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters

I have a method defined in one controller that creates a row in a different controller's table. I'm able to pass all of the data through to create the new row, except for the current user's ID, which I'm trying to grab through params. My user table is set up with devise so I have the current_user method but can't quite figure out the syntax for getting the user_id.

**CONTROLLER_ALPHA**

```
def generate_betas
params[:uni_num].to_i.times do Beta.create(alpha_id: params[:user_id], user_id: params[:alpha_id], rand_num: rand(1000000))
end
end
```

**CONTROLLER_BETA**

```
if current_user.present?
@betas = current_user.betas
else
@betas = Beta.all
```

An alpha has_many :betas
A beta belongs_to :alpha

```
<%= form_tag("/alphas/#{params[:id]}/generate_betas", method:"post") do %>
```

When I pull up the console I'm showing all of the beta elements except for the user_id.

The issue is with that 2nd argument, user_id: params[:alpha_id].  With the current_user method my users can only see the alphas that they've created. Additionally, users are logged in, so I think I should be able to grab it from this method, but I'm not sure how.

Does anyone know the right syntax for grabbing the user_id?

Comment: Please tag the programming language suitable to your question!

Comment: Ugh; can you please reformat and take out the spurious br tags?

Comment: Ruby. Sorry. Adding also the form_tag initiating the event:

<%= form_tag("/alphas/#{params[:id]}/generate_betas", method:"post") do %>

Comment: what does current_user return? can you not call `current_user.id`?

Comment: Processes but user_id comes back = nil in the console with current_user.id. User is logged in.

Comment: Ok.... @PhilVarg - I can hear the collective "OMG" across the Ruby universe, but that's ok. I've been at this for days and I'm just stoked that now It seems to work. I simply put parentheses around the 2nd argument. user_id: (current_user.id). I guess I'd been using brackets. Couldn't see the forrest. Thanks.